# Solving set of linear equations in plaintext using sympy

Tags: python, parsing, linear-algebra, sympy, solver

I would like to add a functionality to solve systems of linear equations to my python based editor. I am looking for a module that would be able to parse a string such as the one below:

```
sample_volume=20
final_concentration=0.55
ethanol_concentration=0.96

final_volume = ethanol_vol+sample_volume
final_concentration*final_volume=ethanol_vol*ethanol_concentration
```

And solve for the values of all variables.

I have implemented a quick and dirty script using sympy that does this, see [here](https://anaconda.org/BjornFJohansson/sympy/notebook) for a Jupyter notebook.

I think that this must have been implemented by someone in a more robust way, I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel here.

Does anyone know of any alternative implementation that are more robust (have tests etc)?

Additionally, according to the sympy docs, `sympy.solveset` should be used instead of `sympy.solve`.
I cannot make this work with a list of equations as in my example. Can someone proficient in sympy guide me how to use solveset with an equation system such as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [2]: sample_volume=20
   ...: final_concentration=0.55
   ...: ethanol_concentration=0.96
   ...: 

In [4]: fv,ev = symbols('fv,ev')

In [5]: expr1 = fv - ev+sample_volume

In [6]: expr2 = final_concentration*fv - ev*ethanol_concentration 

In [7]: solve([expr1,expr2], [fv,ev])
Out[7]: {ev: -26.8292682926829, fv: -46.8292682926829}

# I will recommend to use solveset's linear system solver (linsolve)
In [8]: linsolve([expr1,expr2], [fv,ev])
Out[8]: {(-46.8292682926829, -26.8292682926829)}
```